# OpenVPN seems to connect, yet connect ping anything on the other side

Tags: openvpn, ping

I have installed OpenVPN on my Ubuntu 14.04.04 machine with the intension to connect to the VPN server at work.

Before I connect my route tables look like this:

```
root@chuck-ham-pc:/# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

After I VPN connect the route tables look like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
108.20.23.70    192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
108.20.23.70    192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.13.35   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
```

Way is one destination listed twice?

108.20.23.70 is my server.

however a ping to any machine at the other end results in a:

```
root@chuck-ham-pc:/# ping pear01
ping: unknown host pear01
```

However if I use the address of pear01 I get this:

```
root@chuck-ham-pc:/# ping 10.11.2.16
PING 10.11.2.16 (10.11.2.16) 56(84) bytes of data.
<then the terminal hangs and you have to Ctrl-c to get the promt back>
```

I would appreciate any suggestions or help.

Thank you
Chuck

chuck@chuck-ham-pc:~$ dig bear01 @108.20.23.70

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.4-Ubuntu <<>> bear01 @108.20.23.70
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Comment: Update your DNS servers too.

Comment: `pear01` doesn't look like a FQDN.  @ElliottFrisch is right that you need to update your DNS servers.  You can try modifying `/etc/resolve.conf`.  It seems your routes are fine, as you can ping IPs, but you are not getting DNS information from the VPN.  You can try `dig pear01 @108.20.23.70` to see if your route gateway is also a DNS server for the VPN.

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` (without the e)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see I am new to using askubuntu. Here is the output of the dig command:

- dig pear01 @108.20.23.70
- ; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.4-Ubuntu <<>> pear01 @108.20.23.70
- ;; global options: +cmd
- ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached